# Using React Native Geolocation how do I get other users to display on map?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

Currently creating an application for a company. The user of the application is displayed on the map, and their pets are supposed to display on the map as well. `@react-native-community/geolocation` give you the following information

```
coords: {
   accuracy: 5
   altitude: 0
   altitudeAccuracy: -1
   heading: -1
   latitude: 37.7873589
   longitude: -122.408227
   speed: -1
}
```

I am working with a developer from another company and he is expecting the following information from me in order to send the pet location.

```
{
  "bounds": {
    "northeast": {
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0
    },
    "southwest": {
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0
    }
  },
  "showVets": true,
  "showSightings": true,
  "showLostPets": true,
  "showDogs": true,
  "showCats": true,
  "showOtherPetTypes": true
}
```

Geolocation does not give you the `northeast` and `southwest` coordinates. I am unsure what to tell the developer so that he can update the API send me the correct information. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I attempted to create a function that generates the `northeast` and `southwest` coordinates.

```
const region = {
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  }

  const getMapBoundaries = (region) => {
    const northEast = {
      latitude: region.latitude + region.latitudeDelta / 2,
      longitude: region.longitude + region.longitudeDelta / 2
    }
    const southWest = {
      latitude: region.latitude - region.latitudeDelta / 2,
      longitude: region.longitude - region.longitudeDelta / 2
    }

    return {northEast, southWest}
  }
```

I believe I am off somewhere. How can I improve this function to get the exact coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Just send the same value for both.  Sounds like they are asking for a bounding rectangle range that you *might* be in. You dont have a range, you have an exact location.

Otherwise you'll have to confirm with the other dev about how "fuzzy" your location should be and then add that to both.

If **you're** asking for pets or whatever, it's up to you to define the bounds. If you want everything within a 1 degree offset of your location in terms of latitude and longitude, add 1 to lat/long for northeast and subtract it for southwest.

Comment: That for your response. I spoke to another developer and I guess he is supposed to take my coordinates and create a radius around that. My job is to send him the position of the user.